# reversing a user string input but nothing happens

Tags: javascript

this is run my code snippet, reversing a user string input.
I am trying to take the user input and reverse anything that has been typed. I tried to store the value of the into a new value. then manipulated that variable with some methods.

```js
function reverse_it() {                                      
                     
  
  var to_reverse = document.getElementById('to-reverse').value;        
                                 
  
     var inputValue = to_reverse;
   
   inputValue.split('').reverse().join('');
  
  var reversed = inputValue; 

  
  var output_field = document.getElementById('reversed');
  output_field.innerHTML = reversed;
};
```

```html
<h2>Three-Layer Handlers Exercises</h2>

<hr>

<script src="./handler-reverse.js"></script>

to reverse: <input id='to-reverse' value=''></input> <br>
<button onclick='reverse_it()'>reverse it</button> <br>
<p id='reversed'></p><br>

<hr>

<script src="./handler-sort.js"></script>

to sort: <input id='to-sort' value=''></input> <br>
<button onclick='sort_it()'>sort it</button> <br>
<p id='sorted'></p><br>

<hr>

<script src="./handlers-calculator.js"></script>

first number: <input id='first-number' value=''></input><br>
second number: <input id='second-number' value=''></input> <br>
<button onclick='add()'>+</button> 
<button onclick='subtract()'>-</button> 
<button onclick='multiply()'>*</button> 
<button onclick='divide()'>/</button> <br>
<p id='result'></p>

<br><br>




<hr>  
<hr>  
<a href="http://janke-learning.org" target="_blank"><img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18554853/50098409-22575780-021c-11e9-99e1-962787adaded.png" width="40" height="40"></img> Janke Learning</a>
```

I need to take the user input and reverse. how I can do that. I tried the following code so far but something is wrong:

```js
function reverse_it() {                                      

  // read and process user input
  var to_reverse = document.getElementById('to-reverse').value;        

  // pass user input through core logic


   /* write a script to reverse a string */
   to_reverse.split('').reverse().join('');
  /* assign the result to a variable named 'reversed' */

  var reversed = to_reverse; // place-holder, delete this and start over


  // report result to user
  var output_field = document.getElementById('reversed');
  output_field.innerHTML = reversed;
};
```

Comment: you need an assignment of the new string.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable. `to_reverse.split('').reverse().join('');` will not modify the original string. You need to store result in a variable.

Not only strings all the [Primitive Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values) can't be modified. Arrays are objects they can be modified but some of the methods [Mutator Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods) will change original array. here `split()` and `join()` also don't mutate the original array.

```
function reverse_it() {                                      
  var to_reverse = document.getElementById('to-reverse').value;    

  var reversed = to_reverse.split('').reverse().join('');
  var output_field = document.getElementById('reversed');
  output_field.innerHTML = reversed;
};
```

Comment: It's not just that strings are immutable. There's a bunch of operations and neither split or join change their receiver.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thanks for suggestion. I added a little more info about that.

Comment: I stored the value of to_reverse into a new variable as you suggested but nothing happened too.

Comment: @ab2016d Then you show your code which show this problem.

Comment: @ab2016d Please check [Stack Overflow & run code snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) And create a working snippet in your question to show the non working code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the joined string into a variable or pass it directly to your variable `reversed`.

```
function reverse_it() {                                      
  var to_reverse = document.getElementById('to-reverse').value;        
  var reversed = to_reverse.split('').reverse().join('');
  var output_field = document.getElementById('reversed');
  output_field.innerHTML = reversed;
};
```